# Custom script to create folder in project

Tags: json, shell, package

I want to write a script in my package. Json file which will create a folder and some sub files in my project dynamically.
for example: - if i run the script with name user it should create a user folder inside src folder and some sub files as user.service.js insider user's folder.

i have no idea how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working in linux/unix environment. You can create a bash script

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Get the name of the folder from the user input
read -p "Enter folder name: " folderName

# Create the folder
mkdir "src/$folderName"

# Create sub files in the folder
touch "src/$folderName/$folderName.service.js"
```

And use it to create folder with:

```bash
sh create-user.sh
```